# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Truncate

Tags: c#, linq, ef-core-3.1

Is there a way for EF Core 3.1 on SQL Server to truncate a string?

I know there is a way for dates and numbers by using `DbFunctions.TruncateTime` and `DbFunctions.Truncate`.

For example I have a select expression where I want to truncate the address string:

```
context.Items.Select(x => new ItemModel
    Zipcode = x.Address.Zipcode.Truncate(6)
);
```

This will throw an error:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Truncate(System.String, Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**LINQ to Entities** requires the whole LINQ query expression to be translated to an SQL query. The `Truncate` function cannot be translated by EF, that is why you get that error.

You can try [DbFunctions.Left](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbfunctions.left?view=entity-framework-6.2.0) which returns a given number of the leftmost characters in a string.

```cs
context.Items.Select(x => new ItemModel
    Zipcode = DbFunctions.Left(x.Address.Zipcode, 6)
);
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. And a clear explanation why I did not work.